# Proof by induction Involving Factorials

Tags: induction, proof-verification, factorial

My "factorial" abilities are a slightly rusty and although I know of a few simplifications such as: $(n+1)\,n! = (n+1)!$, I'm stuck

I have to prove by induction that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i-1}{i!} = \frac{n!-1}{n!}$$

I get so far as:
$$\frac{k!-1}{k!} + \frac{(k+1)-1}{(k+1)!} = \frac{(k+1)!(k!-1) + k\cdot k!}{k!(k+1)!}$$

and I know I should get: $$\frac{(k+1)! -1}{(k+1)!}.$$

I don't see how, though. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Instead of taking $k!(k+1)!$ as the common demoninator, simply take $(k+1)!$ as the common denominator. Then $$\frac{k!-1}{k!}+\frac{(k+1)-1}{(k+1)!}=\frac{k!-1}{k!}+\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(k!-1)(k+1)}{(k+1)!}+\frac{k}{(k+1)!}.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: I can't take it from there, severe brain freeze today... so basically i have to simplify (k!-1)(k+1)+k into (k+1)! -1 but i still don't see how, thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: Also, thanks for edditing my "code" i couldn't see how to insert all the math "jargon"

Comment: @pablo: They now have a common denominator. Try combining them and doing a little bit of algebra in the numerator.

Comment: so... (k.k! + k! -k -1 +k) = k.k! +k! -1,

Comment: k.k! + k! = (k+1)! ????

Comment: sorry that was so dumb, yep when i have left k.k! +k! take out k! as common factor... eurgh, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @pablo: Nicely done! You can "accept" my answer if you wish by clicking the check mark. This gives both of us reputation points, and signals to other users that the question has been resolved.